# Wedding of Lakshmi to Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, puranas, marriage, lakshmi

Is there any description anywhere of Lakshmi's wedding to Lord Vishnu? In which Purana? What are the details of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only recently read this chapter, so I found it fairly quickly :)

The marriage of Lakshmi to Vishnu is described in the [Skanda Purana, section 9, chapter 14.](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371753.html)- in fact, the entire chapter is dedicated to that event.

First, it offers a list of who all came:

> God Brahmā; the Lords of created being; Śambhu; Manus; great sages; (twelve) Ādityas; (eight) Vasus; (eleven) Rudras; Siddhas; Gandharvas; Cāraṇas; Sādhyas; (forty-nine) Maruts; (the group of ten gods called) Viśvedevas; presiding deities of quarters; the two Aśvins; the Fire-god; the Moon; Dharma; the Prajāpati himself; Garuḍa; Kinnaras and other groups of gods; serpent-devotees of Viṣṇu; of whom Śeṣa was the first, wives of all the Devas (such as) Sāvitrī, Pārvatī, Pṛthivī, Sarasvatī, Śacī, Gaurī, Śivā, Saṃjñā, Ṛddhi, Svāhā, Rohiṇī, Dhūmorṇā (wife of Yama), Aditi and the lawful wives like Mūrti, Dayā and others; Arundhatī, Śāṇḍilī, Lopāmudrā, Anasūyā and other pious wives of sages; (Rivers like) Gaṅgā, Sarasvatī, Revā, Yamuna, Tapatī (Tapti in north Maharashtra), Candrabhāgā (Chinab), Vipāśā (Bias), Śatadru (Sutlej), Devikā (Devā? or Gogrā), Godāvarī, Kāverī, Kauśikī (Kosī), Kṛṣṇā, Veṇī, Bhīmarathī, the great river Tāmraparṇī, Kṛtamālā (Vaiga near Madura, Tamil Nadu), Vitastā (Jhelum), Nirvindhyā (Kālī-Sindh in Mālvā), Surasā, Carmaṇvatī (Chambal), Payoṣṇī (Pain Gaṅgā), Viśvā and others.
>
> All celestial damsels, of whom Raṃbhā, Ghṛtācī, Viśvācī, Menakā, Tilottamā, and Urvaśī were prominent ones came there.
>
> 10. All the residents of Vaikuṇṭha as well as all the inhabitants of Goloka and important attendants of Viṣṇu came there with great delight.
> 11. All the eight supernatural powers beginning with Aṇimā (Levitation), and nine treasures beginning with Śaṅkha, Padma in their corporal forms came near Śrī.

Next, it explains the atmosphere and setting:

> 12. At that time, for the pleasure of Śrī, full autumnal moon removed all the darkness of the night and the quarters became resplendent.
>     14-15. It was furnished with long rows of thousands of pillars decked with jewels. It was beautified with innumerable wonderful canopies and with plantain trees. It was adorned with rows of heavenly wish-yielding trees bent down with sweet fragrant flowers. It was beautiful and fascinating in its various parts.
> 13. It was shining brilliantly with crores of rows of bejewelled lamps of resplendent light. It appeared bright with arches (beautified) with suspended pearl-laces.
> 14. Seating Śrī on a bejewelled throne there, great sages performed her ablution, preceded by vocal and instrumental music.
>
> 18-19. Airāvata, Puṇḍarīka, Vāmana, Kumuda, Añjana, Puṣpadanta, Sārvabhauma, Supratīka—these elephants presiding over eight cardinal points, making a roaring sound, raised up auspicious gold pitchers and showered her with waters brought from seas in four quarters.
>
> 20. Great rivers in their embodied forms brought waters. Vedas, assuming personal forms, recited Mantras along with sages.
> 21. Sweet-voiced Gandharvas sang. Bevies of the celestial damsels danced. Other groups of Devas played on musical instruments.
> 22. There was a great joy all over the three worlds to all embodied beings. Brāhmaṇas recited Vedic Sūktas of which Śrīsūkta was the first. Ladies sang songs.
> 23. Clouds played upon musical instruments such as instruments of bell metal for beating time. Tabors (Mṛdaṅga drums), instruments called Gomukha, Paṇava, large military drums called Ānaka, Dundubhi drums resounded in heaven.
> 24. There was a shower of saffron accompanied with shouts of victory. For her personal service were the lawful wives (of sages) and supernatural powers (in person).

Then the gifts:

> 25. The Ocean gave two yellow-coloured silken garments and abundant invaluable bejewelled ornaments to her who had taken that auspicious bath.
> 26. Indra brought to her a seat worthy of being occupied by her. Viśvakarmā gave her bangles and rings set with excellent jewels.
> 27. The Moon, her brother, offered her an excellent ornament for the nose (nose ring), and also gave her ornaments set with excellent jewels for her hair.
> 28. The Lotus-born (God Brahmā) gave her a lotus and Sarasvatī presented her a pearl necklace. Nāgas of whom Śeṣa was prominent bestowed on her two ear-rings set with the best of jewels.
> 29. Durgā gave her collyrium and saffron symbolic of good fortune (securing the favour, firm devotion and long life of the husband). Sāvitrī gave her an ornament to be worn on the forehead, Śacī gave her a betel-box.
> 30. The season Spring presented her a flower-garland. Śaṅkara gave her a necklace. God Varuṇa gave her the garland Vaijayantī. Kubera bestowed upon her a bejewelled mirror.
> 31. The Fire-god gave her an invaluable bodice, while Yama bestowed an auspicious umbrella. Others presented her ornaments suitable for the occasion.

And finally, the ceremony:

> The ceremony:
> 32. Then the Ocean asked God Brahmā, “To whom should I offer this daughter endowed with excellent ornaments?” The omniscient Lord then replied:
>
> 33-37. “O storehouse of waters! This your daughter is the mother of mine as well as that of Śiva. It is definite that she is the mother of all Devas and the worlds. She has no other husband than Nārāyaṇa, Vāsudeva, the Supreme Brahman, the Lord of all, the excellent Puruṣa. Therefore, O Ocean, for the felicity of the three worlds give her in marriage with proper (religious) procedure to the Lord who has arrived here in person and taken his seat. By giving her (in marriage) to the Supreme Soul, make your life successful by making your family pure and lift it up from the ocean of Saṃsāra. (Though) you are one, you are known in the world by your seven forms due to the division by seven Dvīpas (continents). By doing this (i.e. offering in marriage), you will obtain great fame.”
>
> 38. Addressed thus by God Brahmā, the Ocean who was delighted and had the hair standing on end, regarded himself as blessed and gave his daughter to Viṣṇu.
> 39. Then after requesting the Lord as per procedure, he performed betrothal (Vāgdāna) and other details. He thus completed the sacred precepts pertaining to marriage-ceremony.
> 40. In the marriage celebrations, Dhanvantari, the Moon-god, Indra and other deities were on the side of the Ocean-god there.
> 41. They were the chief ones in bestowing (things like) clothes, ornaments, vehicles, serving of meals and rendering honours to the relatives of the bridegroom.
>
> 42-43. In the auspicious rite of the marriage-ceremony of Lakṣmī, the following were the prominent ladies: river-goddesses of which Gaṅgā was the first; spouses of Devas beginning with Śacī; wives of Mountain(-gods) like Menā (the wife of Himālaya); Supernatural powers beginning with Aṇimā; Kānti, the lovely wife the Moon-god; and all celestial nymphs, O sage.
>
> 44. Then God Brahmā performed the sportive marriage-ceremony of Nārāyaṇa suitable to and in consideration of his parents Dharma and Mūrti.
>
> 45-46. “This Dharma is the support of the world. He is adorable to all embodied beings. He is worthy of being his father. He is excessively in love with him.
>
> This Mūrti who is well-known as the source of origin of all virtues, this daughter of Dakṣa, the lawful wife (of Dharma) deserves to be (Nārāyaṇa’s) mother.”
>
> 47-48. Then, even on the side of Dharma, participating in the marriage duties these were the prominent ones, O sage: (ṃey were) God Śaṅkara accompanied by Nandīśvara and Gaṇeśa, great sages including Marīci, the lords of subjects (Prajāpatis), the sage Nārada, Vainateya (Garuḍa) and attendants including Nanda and Śrīdāmā.
>
> 49. Durgā, the deity of speech (Vāṇī) who is the mother of Vedas, wives of sages including Anasūyā and all Dharmapatnīs (lawful wives) were the prominent ones among the ladies.
> 50. God Brahmā along with Vedas and others, and Brāhmaṇas who were expert in the Vedas and the procedures of the marriage-ceremony, were on both the sides.
> 51. Then, the Ocean, with the favour of Śrī, immediately procured all the requisites, causing wonderment to Devas.
> 52. He saw that whatever he intended (to have) in his mind, it was instantaneously brought near him. He was, therefore, highly delighted.
> 53. In the middle of that (marriage) hall, he caused (the construction of) the altar for establishing the (holy) fire (in it) by Brāhmaṇas learned in the Vedas.
> 54. He decorated the altar with sandal-paste, flowers, (unbroken) grains of rice etc., and with auspicious colours and water-pots containing sprouts.
> 55. Then Viṣṇu who was bathed by prominent sages chanting Mantras accompanied by the loud tumultuous sound of auspicious musical instruments, wore invaluable clothes, bejewelled ornaments and a splendid celestial crown.
> 56. With all the quarters reverberating with the sound of the musical instruments and the sweet songs of dancing celestial ladies he came along with eulogizing Suras to the ceremonial hall and sat on a seat of gold.
> 57. The Ocean along with his dearest wife Gaṅgā washed his (i.e. Viṣṇu’s) lotus-feet with the stream of excellent water flowing from the spout of a golden pitcher (of a particular shape), and carried that water over his head along with (the heads of) those of the members of his family (by sprinkling it over them).
> 58. Then reciting loudly the auspicious verses (relevant to the occasion), God Brahmā made the Ocean-god give (in marriage) Śrī to Acyuta. Enkindling the sacred fire as per injunctions, he offered oblations (to the marital fire) along with sages.
> 59. After giving him his beautiful daughter who had fixed her sight only on his lotus-feet, he presented the great being numerous rich garments and bejewelled ornaments along with the daughter.
> 60. Then Hari circumambulated the duly oblated sacrificial fire along with Śrī, attracting awhile the minds of men and women onlookers.
> 61. The multitudes of gods, along with their wives, worshipped with reverence, the beautiful parents of the universe occupying the same seat, presenting to them invaluable garments and ornaments.
> 62. Goddesses including Durgā and others and wives of Devas including Śacī, whose beautiful faces were beaming with smiles, sang auspicious songs describing the excellences of Viṣṇu.
>
> 63-64. The multitudes of the wives of Devas seated in two groups facing each other, sang with great love and devotion, festive nuptial songs at the sight of the couple in such a way as on hearing them all Suras, great sages, all womenfolk saw the Lord along with Śrī shining within themselves, and they sat (still and motionless) as if drawn in a picture.
>
> 65. Paying obeisance with devotion and offering ceremonial akṣata (unbroken grains of rice) etc., the Devas joyously eulogized them individually, with excellent words, humbly folding their palms with reverence.

(I think that there may be one other mention of the marriage in a different Purana, I'll try to look for that, too.)